# Why does this print 3 ln 8 4?

Tags: java, arrays

```
boolean[][] values = new boolean[3][4];
System.out.println(values.length);
values[2] = new boolean[8];
System.out.println(values[2].length + " " + values[0].length);
```

This is a multiple choice question that I'm having trouble with. The answer is supposed to be:

```
3
8 4
```

but I thought that an array's size cannot be changed once it is created. Any explanations would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are not changing the length of an array, you are creating a new one of a different length.

Comment: You are making a "jagged array".

Comment: I don't think this question is that bad. After all, the array was initialized as `boolean[3][4]`, and now is is no longer `boolean[3][4]` but "ragged", i.e. `boolean[3][whatever]`.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted so much

Answer (score 2):

You are not changing the length of an array, you are creating a new one of a different length.

```
values[2] = new boolean[4]; 
assert values[2].length == 4;

values[2] = new boolean[8]; 
assert values[2].length == 8;
```

is just like writing

```
boolean[] values2 = new boolean[4]; 
assert values2.length == 4;

values2 = new boolean[8]; 
assert values2.length == 8;
```

Note: a `boolean[]` variable is a *reference* to an array. It is not the array object so when you change this *reference* you point to a different object.

Answer (score 2):

```
values = new boolean[3][4]
```

... creates an array of length 3, pointed to by a variable called `values`. Each of the three elements in `values` points to an array of length 4.

So:

```
System.out.println(values.length);
```

... prints 3.

```
values[2] = new boolean[8];
```

... creates a new array of length 8, and makes element 2 of `values` point to it.

The array that used to be element 2 of values no longer has a reference -- it's lost (if the JVM stays around long enough, it will be cleared away by garbage collection).

`values[0]` is still the 4 element array created at the start. `values[2]` is the newly created array of length 8.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, two-dimensional arrays are actually arrays of arrays, not a block of bytes that's divided into rows, as it is in some other languages.

When you declare an array as

```
boolean[][] values = new boolean[3][4];
```

It's basically just a shorthand to writing:

```
boolean[][] values = {
     new boolean[4],
     new boolean[4],
     new boolean[4]
};
```

So you have an array whose elements are arrays of booleans.

There is nothing stopping you from changing one of the entries in this array. You have a first array, a second array, and a third array, and you are just replacing the third.

Thus, it is not changing the size of the array, because the declaration `new boolean[3][4]` only sets a fixed size for the first dimension, and for the initial values (arrays) in it. But you can replace those initial values with new values which have a different size if you wish - as long as you don't try to change the size of the main array.